# WPF screen freeze use Dispatcher BeginInvoke methods

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, freeze, dispatcher

I have an issue with the WPF usage with loops and frozen screen.
my example code is here

```
private void Btn1_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
            o =>
            {
                FaturaCount.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
                {
                    int a = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000000; i++)
                    {
                        a = a + i;
                    }
                    txtCount.Text = a.ToString();
                }, DispatcherPriority.Background);
            });

    }
```

the screen freezes while the loop continues. 
I want to make loop work at back and the screen still be used until it finished.
Why is happening and how can i fix this?

Comment: You're starting a thread which then does all of its work in the UI thread. Instead of putting the entire loop in the Invoke lambda, just invoke for teh one tiny little part where you need to touch the UI -- or, much, much better yet, write a viewmodel and update `txtCount.Text` via a binding, which will do the invoke for you and you won't even have to think about the dispatcher.

Comment: I putted loop below the thread and it fixed my issue. Thank for answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you "invoke into a thread", you're telling that thread to stop whatever it's doing and execute your code instead.

So you're starting a thread which promptly blocks the UI thread while it does all of its work there. That wasn't your intent.

Instead of putting the entire loop in the Invoke lambda, just invoke for the one tiny little part where you need to touch the UI:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
    o =>
    {
        int a = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000000; i++)
        {
            a = a + i;
            FaturaCount.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                txtCount.Text = a.ToString();
            });
        }
    });
```

Clearly, the above code doesn't do anything useful, and such rapid repeated calls to Invoke don't make much sense. That'll tie up the UI very nearly as badly as your original version. Modern hardware can increment integers and iterate loops very, very quickly. Is this your actual code, or is the loop in the thread actually doing something more useful, with longer intervals between UI updates? If I were implementing a thread that just displayed an incrementing integer in a TextBlock, I'd put a Thread.Sleep(250) or something in the loop outside the Invoke. Give the UI a chance to respond to user input.

Or, much, much better yet, since this is WPF, write a viewmodel and update `txtCount.Text` via a binding, which will do the invoke for you. You won't even have to think about the dispatcher then.

Comment: Scheduling an infinite number of updates to a textbox is going to freeze the UI just as hard as the OP's code will, assuming it doesn't just crash the whole program entirely by blowing the message pump's capacity.

Comment: @Servy Quite true. I suppose I should confirm with OP that this is just a simplified example.

Comment: Hi. actually I am using viewmodel for this process. I simplified the code for clear understandling thanks for the answers

Comment: @MuratAras Excellent. Glad I could help.